ABRSM Grade 8 theory true or false question
I was doing a practice paper and I feel so silly for not being able to figure this out but the question is: True or false? The celesta and xylophone sound in unison on the first beat of bar 1
I thought that both instruments were playing the same E. Does the celesta not sound an octave higher or am I being silly? Thank you



These notes sound an octave apart, because both are transposing instruments, sounding an octave above written pitch.

Ohhhhh thank you!! Somehow made it to grade 8 without knowing the xylophone sounds one octave up too

No problem! Happy to help. And welcome to Music.SE!

BTW, this is a useful question. You could make it even more useful for future readers by mentioning xylophone and transposition in the title and tags maybe…?

But is this answer "True" or "False"? If an SATB choir sings "in unison" it means everyone is singing an E (for example), but not necessarily in the same octave.

No, strictly speaking (which music theory is) an octave and a unison are not the same thing.

When one talks informally about a choir singing “in unison” (for example singing a hymn melody), strictly speaking they are actually singing “in octaves”. Unless of course they are truly singing in unison with the female voices near the bottom of their range and the men near the top. Same with cellos and basses in many orchestral scores: they are doubled “in octaves”. You wouldn’t say they were in unison.

This question is about a music theory exam, where exact meanings and terminology should be used, not informal terminology.

Everyone is focusing on the pitch, but maybe it's worth to also add a short explanation regarding different note values?

'Strictly speaking' - wish it was, but sometimes it falls more into 'loosely speaking' which is one reason this site exists!

Afraid I disagree slightly with the existing answer. Both celeste and xylophone are transposing instruments, their notation being written an octave below the pitch they sound at.
Since the written pitches are already an octave apart, both will play notes sounding an octave above those E  notes, and thus will still be an octave apart.
Unison usually means when instruments play the same notes in the same octaves, which will not happen here. Thus the answer is they will not play in unison.
Hence, the answer to the question must be false.
HOWEVER - unison can also mean two or more notes played simultaneously in different octaves!
Hence the answer must be true.
FURTHER TO THIS ANSWER - there are in fact two different kinds of unison - perfect and rhythmic. Looking at the second, rhythmic unison happens when two or more instruments play simultaneously, the same rhythmic pattern is used, but different notes are played, usually forming chords. As the example shows a dotted minim for the celeste, and a dotted crotchet for the xylophone, it cannot be a rhythmic unison. Answer - false.
Concerning the perfect unison, then yes, the same pitch is played by both, so the answer is true.
The phrase 'sound in unison' needs to be clarified: are in unison, or play in unison would be a step in the right direction. A great example of a poor question, far too ambiguous for ABRSM, I believe!
In the past, I've spoken to those at ABRSM about spurious questions/answers, and they've been very helpful. That would have been my first action.

Because there are the two meanings of "unison", is the ABRSM exam question malformed, or is there an implied definition operative in the context of an ABRSM question (cf @BobBroadley's comment)?  If the latter, where should one learn of these preferred definitions?  I think providing a source where an exam taker can learn these ABRSM definitions can add value to your answer.

Another unexplained dv! Please explain what you felt was wrong with this answer, and what could be done to make it better. It's so easy to anonymously award a dv - I could do dozens a day, but have more respect.

it wasn't me, I in fact up voted this answer.  Thanks for the update.

It's false, using the strictest meaning of 'unison'.
But it's a bad question, illustrating the worst features of the AB theory exams' descent into mere 'box ticking'.
A good teacher, having established the point that both xylophone and celeste are transposing instruments, sounding an octave above written pitch, would have followed up with a discussion of the various common usages of the term 'unison'.
